# How to uninstall Facebook Messenger from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-uninstall

Recently I installed Facebook Messenger in my Ubuntu 14.04 and then I noticed that it is no longer supported in Ubuntu. So I tried to uninstall it. When I checked Software Center I can't find an entry for Facebook Messenger there.

The following are the commands I used to install Facebook Messenger:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fbmessenger
```

So how can I uninstall Facebook Messenger ?

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get remove fbmessenger` ?

Comment: @Antaraz Yes.. It worked.

Comment: I tried the solutions you proposed, but the Icon in the launcher is still there. And if I click again on it, the facebook messenger (which works horrible on Ubuntu) appears again...
Is there a way to uninstall it completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the package "fbmessenger" from the Software Center or run:

```
sudo apt-get remove fbmessenger
```

Comment: you probably also want to remove the ppa you added for this: `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` (the `-r` option is for removal)

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-facebookmessenger
```

This worked for me. In fact googleplus, gmail... are all unity-webapps-*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the ppa anymore, the best way could be to first install ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

and then run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

this uninstalls all the packages from this ppa, and disables the ppa as well, quite handy if you have a lot of ppas

Answer (score -1):

Run this :

```
sudo dpkg -r fbmessenger
```

Comment: It didn't worked.