# E: Unable to locate package fbmessenger

Tags: apt, uninstall

I accidentally clicked on Install for Facebook Messenger in Ubuntu 14.04. The icon appears on the left bar. However, when I try to remove the package (following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/471971/412960) answer), I am getting:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ sudo apt-get remove fbmessenger
[sudo] password for gsamaras: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fbmessenger
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$
```

How should I remove it?

Comment: When visiting [that](http://askubuntu.com/a/471971/412960), you had not tried [that](http://askubuntu.com/a/520881/256099)?

Comment: Oh damn @Pandya, how could I miss it? To be honest, I do not remember. Sorry about that, will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your terminal and type:

> `sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-facebookmessenger`

This should remove the app.